# Parse string value via attribute c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes

I'm using `ASP.NET MVC` and I have the follwoing model class:

```
public enum ListType
{
    black,
    white
}
public class ListAddSiteModel : ApiModel
{
    [RequestParameter]
    public ListType list { get; set; }
}
```

But it doesn't work the way I want. When I don't pass list parameter in the requested `URL` I have that list is `black`. But I want that if the list parameter is not `black` or `white` string then `list` must be null. Is it possible to write custom attribute `[IsParsable]` and just add it to the list property.

```
public class ListAddSiteModel : ApiModel
{
    [RequestParameter]
    [IsParsable]
    public ListType list { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `list` cannot be null as an `enum` is not a nullable type. You should define it as `public ListType? list` or else give ListType a default value (`ListType.none`) - also you should capitalize those enum and property names

Comment: @RGraham What does question mark mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can pass a value that is *not* black or white, is to pass an `int`. You can prevent that by adding a check in your setter that calls [Enum.IsDefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), eg:

```
ListType? _listType;
public ListType? List
{
    get
    { 
        return _listType;
    }
    set
    {
        //Enumb.IsDefined doesn't like nulls
        if (value==null || Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ListType),value))
            _listType=value;
        else
            _listType=null;
    }
}
```

You can also combine this with Henk Holterman's answer and add an `NA` member equal to 0 in your enumeration. This will probably make your code easier to read.

In both cases your code will have to take care of the special values (`NA` or `null`). Using a nullable type makes it harder to forget this, but does litter your code a bit.

Comment: What does question mark in the `ListType? _listType;` mean. This contruction is ungooglable.

Comment: This is the C# syntax for a [nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx). It's used to allow handling of nulls for value types that would otherwise not allow null values. It's in C# since .NET 2.0, so it's practically everywhere.

Comment: Is the explicit property declaration required here? Won't MVC automatically bind a nullable enum to `null` if the provided value is not found within the type?

Comment: @RGraham This won't prevent user code from passing a bad value. If that's not a concern, you could just keep the nullable declaration.

Answer (score 4):

Easy way out:

```
public enum ListType
{
    novalue = 0, 
    black,
    white
}
```

the dummy must be first (map to `0 == default(Enum)`)

Comment: Still won't prevent someone from passing an invalid value, if that was the actual question